# Add Join Widget

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am trying to build a web application on ArcGIS online and was wondering if anyone knew of a widget what would allow me to join data from one file to another based on a attribute. I know there is a tool in ArcMap called Add Join tool but I could not find a substitute within Web App Builder.

Comment: According to [this link](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012168), building joins is currently not supported in ArcGIS Online.  See the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own custom Join widget with Python and JavaScript.

I built my own custom Join Widget by writing up the join processing script in Python, and then publishing it as a geoprocessing script. I then customized Web App Builder's default Geoprocessing script to reference to the geoprocessing service and customized the user interface to meet the needs of the project.

Comment: Did you python code look like this?                                                              import arcpy
input_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
join_table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
join_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
arcpy.AddJoin_management("input_layer","in_field","join_table","join_field","KEEP_ALL")

Comment: Yes, you can use that syntax for the Join geoprocessing. You can remove the quotes from input_layer, in_field, and join_table though since you are storing the parameters as variables.  Don't forget to create a parameter for the output and use the SetParameter function to get the join output to display. More info here: [link](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/setparameter.htm)

Comment: Ifeoma, could you explain this in a little more detail I am confused as to how this work. If you set a parameter for an output such as **output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)** and use the function SetParameter like so **arcpy.SetParameter(1, output)** how will that call the data from the join? Maybe I am doing this wrong?

Comment: Here is my new code:                                                                                import arcpy
input_layer1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
join_table1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
join_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
input_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_layer1, "inputlayer.lyr")
join_table = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(join_table1, "join_table.lyr")
test = arcpy.AddJoin_management(input_layer,in_field,join_table,join_field, "KEEP_ALL")
arcpy.SetParameter(1, output)

Comment: If the output is parameter 4 for your tool, then you can just do something like this for the output: arcpy.SetParameter(4, output). Assign the output variable to be the final result you want to display in the map before you do SetParameter instead of doing a GetParameter for the output.

Comment: So I kept everything the same and changed the last line to `arcpy.GetParameter(4,output)` and on the Parameters page of the script wizard I signified the direction of the the output layer to Output, but it still will not add the layer to the map even though it says that it was created. Any idea as to why that would happen?

Comment: Remove output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4) and do output = input_layer.  The last line should use SetParameter for the output not GetParameter.

Comment: So this? import arcpy
input_layer1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
join_table1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
join_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
input_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_layer1, "inputlayer.lyr")
join_table = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(join_table1, "join_table.lyr")
arcpy.AddJoin_management(input_layer,in_field,join_table,join_field, "KEEP_ALL")
output = input_layer
arcpy.SetParameter(4,output) I still get an error .SetParameter(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in setting parameter

Comment: Oh make sure you are consistent with your input layer variable name. I see both input _layer and input _layer1. Same with join_table and join_table1.

Comment: Even with those changed to both input_layer and join_table like below made no difference. Any idea?: import arcpy
input_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
join_table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
join_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
input_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_layer, "inputlayer.lyr")
join_table = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(join_table, "join_table.lyr")
arcpy.AddJoin_management(input_layer,in_field,join_table,join_field, "KEEP_ALL")
output = input_layer
arcpy.SetParameter(4,output)

Comment: You assigned the input _layer and join _layer variable twice. Remove their make feature layer assignments.

Comment: Great! Can you please mark one of my comments as the answer so people know that the problem was solved? Thanks.